# getModificationTime return type is no longer System.ClockTime

Tags: haskell, time

I'm reading *Real World Haskell*; in chapter 9 the example uses a function `getModificationTime` from `System.Directory`, which had a return type of `ClockTime`, but I think in the newer version of System.Directory, it has a different return type.
    :t getModificationTime returns this:

```
getModificationTime
:: FilePath -> IO time-1.4.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime
```

I can get it to work by

```
import Data.Time.Clock
```

But my question is, why the new return type is

```
IO time-1.4.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime
```

not just `UTCTime`? is it because the type is from a module that's not imported?

And what's the difference between `System.Time` and `Data.Time.Clock`? Is the latter preferable?

Comment: Which version of GHC are you using?

Comment: The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended time functions have changed. `Data.Time` etc. from the `time` package is a complete and more logical rewrite of Haskell's time functions. To quote the top of 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/old-time-1.1.0.2/docs/System-Time.html:

> The standard time library from Haskell 98. This library is deprecated, please look at Data.Time in the time package instead.

Comment: thanks, do you know what the type time-1.4.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime mean? is the bit before : there because I didn't import the library?

Comment: @swang Yes, that's the reason. The part before `:` is the package name, then comes the module name and then the type name itself. So if you import the module it all becomes just `UTCTime`.